# Mapping row values to column names and assign 1 to the column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `dataframes`. The first `dataframe` is `df` and the second one is `df2`.

`df`=

[image]

`df2` = [image]

How can I map values from `df` 'Numbers' column to the columns in `df2`? For an instance One in 'Numbers' column is mapped to Col_One in `df2` and the value for `Col_One` first row is 1. The numbers in `df2` are added based on the row numbers in `df`. Sample output as below
:

`df2` =

[image]

Comment: Please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide the input / output dataframes along with your explanation. It'll improve your odds of getting a good answer.

Comment: Are you implementing one hot encoding?

Comment: Hi @VisheshMangla, you are absolutely right. But I don't want to use the get_dummies function. Is there any other way to do this? possible with df.apply? I tried, but no success.

Comment: Haven't you learned sklearn? Don't reinvent the wheel. It's a time waste to reimplement that. Use https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html. Lots of videos are available on youtube if you  are comfortable with videos more.

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh, thank you for your kind suggestion. First time posting, so I know it may not be very clear. I'll improve the post. Thanks!

Comment: @VisheshMangla, yup I am aware of that. But, I would like to know if there are any other options to do this. May be useful for other scenarios.

Comment: well, tensorflow, scikit-learn both have OneHotEncoder.  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot

Comment: @VisheshMangla, thank you for your kind suggestions